# R Shiny wait for session to be free before next instruction

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where I want to visit each tab automatically and wait until the rendering of a tab is completed before moving to the next one.
(The background of this is, that this does some calculation and builds a cache. But this is not strictly speaking part of the question I guess.)

I have a simple app like this with three tabs (that when accessed print a message to the screen and to the console).
The app has a reactive value `current_tab()` that allows me to go to a tab automatically.

Then at the end I loop over all tabs to render the tab.
:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tab_panel",
      tabPanel("tab1", h1("This is Tab 1"), textOutput("txt1")),
      tabPanel("tab2", h1("This is Tab 2"), textOutput("txt2")),
      tabPanel("tab3", h1("This is Tab 3"), textOutput("txt3"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # 1. Render some text to the textOutput ----
  # use print to also print the text to the console
  output$txt1 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 1"))
  output$txt2 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 2"))
  output$txt3 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 3"))
  
  # 2. Create a reactiveVal that allows me to go to a tab ----
  current_tab <- reactiveVal()
  observe(cat(sprintf("Currently on tab %s\n", current_tab())))
  # move to the tab
  observeEvent(current_tab(), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tab_panel", selected = current_tab())
  })
  
  # 3. Iterate through all tabs and render them ----
  tabs <- c("tab1", "tab2", "tab3")
  for (tab in tabs) {
    print(paste("Trying to move to Tab", tab))
    current_tab(tab)
    # Wait until the session is free again before moving to the next one?!
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately (and this is the main part of the question), the for loop iterates to quickly over the tabs so that the tabs are not rendered (in the output we start with tab 1, which is rendered, then the for loop jumps to 2 (skipping the rendering part), then to 3 which is rendered because the loop is done and the session has time to render it).

In the end, I need the text `Rendering Text X` shown in the console for all three tabs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

edit: old answer at bottom, new answer on top

you could do something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tab_panel",
      tabPanel("tab1", h1("This is Tab 1"), textOutput("txt1")),
      tabPanel("tab2", h1("This is Tab 2"), textOutput("txt2")),
      tabPanel("tab3", h1("This is Tab 3"), textOutput("txt3"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  content1<-reactive(
    print("Rendering Text 1")
    )
  content2<-reactive(
    print("Rendering Text 2")
  )
  content3<-reactive(
    print("Rendering Text 3")
  )
  output$txt1 <- renderText({
    content1()
    })
  output$txt2 <- renderText({
    content2()})
  output$txt3 <- renderText({
    content3()
})
  
  observe(
    list(content1(),
         content2(),
         content3())
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

if you want to disable the laziness of certain aspects of shiny (use with caution) you can do so like this.
This acheives your desired effect.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tab_panel",
      tabPanel("tab1", h1("This is Tab 1"), textOutput("txt1")),
      tabPanel("tab2", h1("This is Tab 2"), textOutput("txt2")),
      tabPanel("tab3", h1("This is Tab 3"), textOutput("txt3"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # 1. Render some text to the textOutput ----
  # use print to also print the text to the console
  output$txt1 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 1"))
  output$txt2 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 2"))
  output$txt3 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 3"))
  outputOptions(output, "txt2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "txt3", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but I don't want to change the responsiveness of Rendertext in this case

Comment: The second answer (on top) also involves changing the reactive layout of the app. The app that I want to apply this to is a bit more complex and changing it so deeply is something I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The below updated code snippet might help.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tab_panel",
      tabPanel("tab1", h1("This is Tab 1"), textOutput("txt1")),
      tabPanel("tab2", h1("This is Tab 2"), textOutput("txt2")),
      tabPanel("tab3", h1("This is Tab 3"), textOutput("txt3")),
      tabPanel("tab4", h1("This is Tab 4"), textOutput("txt4")),
      tabPanel("tab5", h1("This is Tab 5"), textOutput("txt5"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # A core feature of Shiny is that it doesn't attempt to render controls it thinks are hidden. Read more at https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1243

  # need to run once to update the shiny default behavior of an output element ----
  # preferably at the start of the server
  # observe & isolate combination is used to run a reactive context only once in the app lifetime
  observe({
    isolate({
      # for this example, we need to update the default behavior for only tab 2
      outputOptions(output, "txt2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

      # additional tabs for demo
      outputOptions(output, "txt3", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
      outputOptions(output, "txt4", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

      # safe-gaurd for initial and last tabs
      outputOptions(output, "txt1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
      outputOptions(output, "txt5", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
    })
  })


  # 1. Render some text to the textOutput ----
  # use print to also print the text to the console
  output$txt1 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 1"))
  output$txt2 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 2"))
  output$txt3 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 3"))
  output$txt4 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 4"))
  output$txt5 <- renderText(print("Rendering Text 5"))

  # 2. Create a reactiveVal that allows me to go to a tab ----
  current_tab <- reactiveVal()

  observe({
    cat(sprintf("Currently on tab %s\n", current_tab()))
  })
  # move to the tab
  observeEvent(current_tab(), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tab_panel", selected = current_tab())
  })

  # 3. Iterate through all tabs and render them ----
  tabs <- c("tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4", "tab5")
  for (tab in tabs) {
    print(paste("Trying to move to Tab", tab))
    current_tab(tab)
    # Wait until the session is free again before moving to the next one?!
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Output

[image]